# gettin this error ,TemplateSyntaxError at / Could not parse the remainder: '>=18' from '>=18'

Tags: python, django

Gettin this error, TemplateSyntaxError at / Could not parse the remainder: '>=18' from '>=18' and my code is written here,

```
 <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          
          <th scope="col">S.No</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Age</th>
          <th scope="col">Can Vote </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for people in people %}
        <tr>
          
          <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
          <td>{{people.name}}</td>
          <td>{{people.age}}</td>
          <td>
             {% if people.age >=18 %}
             can Vote
             {% else %}
            can't Vote
             {% endif %}          
          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am trying to create a django project which detects yu can vote or not

Comment: just add a space before 18. like this: {% if people.age >= 18 %}